# Как сделать "уведомление" о том, что собеседник отправил тебе сообщение

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

У меня реализован простой мессенджер. Каким образом можно сделать "уведомление" о том, что какой-либо собеседник тебе написал сообщение. Вот например, пользователь номер 1 пишет сообщение пользователю номер 2, и у пользователя номер 2 должен показаться значок о том, что есть непрочитанное сообщение и все это без перезагрузки страницы. Я думаю это надо делать с помощью сигналов, websocket, django-channels, но как... это я не знаю.

Comment: И еще должно обновиться строчка последнего сообщения, я думаю это связано с этой проблемой

Comment: Лучше удалите этот вопрос, прочитайте интструкцию как задавать вопросы и задайте заного. На ваш поток сознания невозможно ответить

Comment: прочитайте еще раз